# StackOverflow if using Parallel.For

Tags: c#, recursion, parallel.for

I'm currently trying to make a code, that will help to count efficient reactors set for game StarMade.
I'm using recursive method to explore the 3d tree of elements and find all related groups. For ex. group - it's a cluster of elements, that stay close to each other.
On picture something like this:

```
XOX
OOX
XXO
```

where O is nothing, and X is reactor (element).
On this picture there are 3 groups of elements. [0,0], [2,0]-[2,1], [0,2]-[1,2]
Another variant:

```
XXX
OOX
XXX
```

Here is only one group, because all elements stay close to each other.
Here is my code:

```
 void CheckGroup(int x, int y, int z, Group group)
    {
        if(x >= maxz || x < 0 || y >= maxy || y < 0 || z >= maxz || z < 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (reactorsChecked[x, y, z])
        {
            return;
        }
        reactorsChecked[x, y, z] = true;
        if (reactors[x, y, z])
        {
            if (group == null)
            {
                group = new Group();
                group.MaxX = x;
                group.MaxY = y;
                group.MaxZ = z;
                group.MinX = x;
                group.MinY = y;
                group.MinZ = z;
                group.Blocks = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                group.MaxX = Math.Max(group.MaxX, x);
                group.MaxY = Math.Max(group.MaxY, y);
                group.MaxZ = Math.Max(group.MaxZ, z);
                group.MinX = Math.Min(group.MinX, x);
                group.MinY = Math.Min(group.MinY, y);
                group.MinZ = Math.Min(group.MinZ, z);
                group.Blocks += 1;
            }

            CheckGroup(x + 1, y, z, group);
            CheckGroup(x - 1, y, z, group);

            CheckGroup(x, y + 1, z, group);
            CheckGroup(x, y - 1, z, group);

            CheckGroup(x, y, z + 1, group);
            CheckGroup(x, y, z - 1, group);

            if (!groups.Contains(group))
            {
                groups.Add(group);
            }
        }
    }
```

group - is simple class for cluster, that store data about elements count in this cluster and bounding box of this cluster.
reactorsChecked - is simple bool[,,] array, that store information about elements, that we have checked, to avoid doubles
reactor - simple bool[,,] array of random elements.
At first I insert random values to reactors array, and then call CheckGroup(x,y,z,null). If reactors array size less then 25x25x25, then all ok. In single thread size of array could be 100x100x100 and all would be ok. But if I try to use Parallel.For, then I got StackOverflow after near 9000 recursions...
Here is full code:

```
Parallel.For(0, Environment.ProcessorCount, (i) =>
            {
                Calculator calc = new Calculator(x, y, z, max, cycles);
                calcs.Add(calc);
            });

public class Calculator
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    //List<Group> groups = new List<Group>();
    HashSet<Group> groups = new HashSet<Group>();
    bool[, ,] reactors;
    public bool[, ,] reactorsMax;
    bool[, ,] reactorsChecked;
    public double maxEnergy = 0;
    public string result = "";
    public string resultPic = "";

    int maxx, maxy, maxz;

    public Calculator(int x, int y, int z, int max, int cycles)
    {
        maxx = x;
        maxy = y;
        maxz = z;
        maxEnergy = max;
        for (int i = 0; i < cycles; i++)//check few variants per thread
        {
            Calculate(x,y,z);
        }
    }

    private void Calculate(int X, int Y, int Z)
    {
        //groups = new List<Group>();
        groups = new HashSet<Group>();

        reactors = new bool[X, Y, Z];

        for (int x = 0; x < X; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < Y; y++)
            {
                for (int z = 0; z < Z; z++)
                {
                    reactors[x, y, z] = rnd.Next(2)==1;//fill array with random values
                }
            }
        }

        reactorsChecked = new bool[X, Y, Z];
        for (int x = 0; x < X; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < Y; y++)
            {
                for (int z = 0; z < Z; z++)
                {
                    CheckGroup(x, y, z, null);//start calculations
                }
            }
        }
        double sum = 0;
        int blocks = 0;
        foreach(Group g in groups)
        {
            float dims = g.MaxX - g.MinX + g.MaxY - g.MinY + g.MaxZ - g.MinZ + 3;
            sum += (2000000.0f / (1.0f + Math.Pow(1.000696f, (-0.333f * Math.Pow((dims / 3.0f), 1.7)))) - 1000000.0f + 25.0f * g.Blocks);
            blocks += g.Blocks;
        }

        if (sum > maxEnergy)
        {
            maxEnergy = sum;

            reactorsMax = reactors;
        }

    }

    void CheckGroup(int x, int y, int z, Group group)
    {
        if(x >= maxz || x < 0 || y >= maxy || y < 0 || z >= maxz || z < 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (reactorsChecked[x, y, z])
        {
            return;
        }
        reactorsChecked[x, y, z] = true;
        if (reactors[x, y, z])
        {
            if (group == null)
            {
                group = new Group();
                group.MaxX = x;
                group.MaxY = y;
                group.MaxZ = z;
                group.MinX = x;
                group.MinY = y;
                group.MinZ = z;
                group.Blocks = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                group.MaxX = Math.Max(group.MaxX, x);
                group.MaxY = Math.Max(group.MaxY, y);
                group.MaxZ = Math.Max(group.MaxZ, z);
                group.MinX = Math.Min(group.MinX, x);
                group.MinY = Math.Min(group.MinY, y);
                group.MinZ = Math.Min(group.MinZ, z);
                group.Blocks += 1;
            }

            CheckGroup(x + 1, y, z, group);
            CheckGroup(x - 1, y, z, group);

            CheckGroup(x, y + 1, z, group);
            CheckGroup(x, y - 1, z, group);

            CheckGroup(x, y, z + 1, group);
            CheckGroup(x, y, z - 1, group);

            if (!groups.Contains(group))
            {
                groups.Add(group);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

So the main question - is it possible to avoid stackOverflow in Parallel.For, or to rewrite it to iteration loop?

Parallel.For using default stackSize value even if you will use

```
Thread(()=>
{
    Parallel.For(...);
},stackSize).Start()
```

it will use default values...

I don't like variant like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < cpuCount; i++)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(()=>{calculate();},stackSize).Start()
}
```

because I have to manage all threads, wait while all finishes, so it makes code very complicated... May be there are easier things?

Comment: What depth of recursion do you reach in a single thread for the same input? It sounds like you should rewrite the code to avoid recursing so deeply anyway, to be honest.

Comment: @JonSkeet, in single thread depth of recursion with 50x50x50 array was more than 200.000, and all works fine. With Parallel.For depth was near 9000 and all crashed with stackOverflow...

Comment: That's interesting. Running a simple test on my laptop, I only get a recursion depth of 21,000 for a method which just has a single parameter and no other local variables. For a depth of 200K with 4 parameters, that sounds like an awful lot of stack... (Although neither of these seems to match a default stack of 1MB...)

Comment: 200.000 was able, when I changed stack size in Thread.

Comment: Ah, well that explains it - you never mentioned changing the stack size of the single thread you're using. What do you get if you don't do that?

Comment: I tried without modifying stackSize - near 8.000 recursions. Tried array 50x50x50. With modify stackSize - program makes all calculations without error.

Comment: Right. You should really explain that in your question - it's entirely reasonable that the threads used by Parallel.For use the default stack size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options:

1. to use recursion and try to increase the stack size (by using the [`Thread(ThreadStart, maxStackSize)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/5cykbwz4.aspx) constructor). The stack in applications is usually set to 1MB (see [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686774.aspx) for details). Especially in DEBUG mode without optimizations (no inlining optimization done) this is a very limited value. Having a thread with separate stack for every `Paralllel.For()` statement
   might help.
2. Use a iteration look instead of recursion to handle the stack depth by yourself.

I personally would go with option 1. (with or without separate stack) only in case I known the maximum depth of my recursion.

My preferred solution in most cases like yours will be the iteration approach.

Edit by @LordXaosa:
I tried this, and all works fine

```
int stackSize = 1024*1024*1024;//1GB limit
ManualResetEvent[] mre = new ManualResetEvent[Environment.ProcessorCount];
Parallel.For(0, Environment.ProcessorCount, (i) =>
{
     mre[i] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
     Thread t = new Thread((object reset) =>
     {
           Calculator calc = new Calculator(x, y, z, max, cycles);
           calcs.Add(calc);
           ManualResetEvent m = (ManualResetEvent)reset;
           m.Set();
     }, stackSize / (Environment.ProcessorCount * 4));
     t.Start(mre[i]);
});
WaitHandle.WaitAll(mre);
```

But there also a limit... 50x50x50 array works fine, but more - stack overflow... In original game it can process 1000x1000x1000 sets, so may be there is another algorithm.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, I tried stack size in thread with Parallel.For. Or you would like to propose me to use something like Parallel.For(0, n, (i)=>{new Thread(..., stacksize).Start()}); ?

Comment: Yes, create the thread inside the `Parallel.For()` action. Anyhow, as long as you cannot predict the depth of your recursion, this might fail as well (but later :-))

Comment: It makes code more complicated, because I should make thread pool and wait, while all this threads will finish. In that way I don't need Parallel.For... I could use simple for, in loop make new threads... I really don't like this variant :(

Comment: Stephen, do you know how to convert this recursion to iteration loop?

Comment: you may use a class to contain x, y, z and group together with a Stack (see msdn). initially `push (0,0,0, new Group(/* either null or initialized based on reactors[0,0,0] set */)`. Then to `while (stack.Count() > 0) { var current = stack.pop(); /* your logic ... */`; then instead of recursion, `stack.push(...)` 6 times... This is just a rough idea, I didn't went into your code in that detail. There is a [good article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/418776/How-to-replace-recursive-functions-using-stack-and) which explains this in detail...